# Traversing json using with square brackets with jsx

Tags: json, jsx

I need some help with my syntax please in trying to get thevalue from a key. Given the following json object:

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "id": "recD17v5uIGpA7jYU",
        "fields": {
            "header h1": "Clouds",
            "Email": 1,
            "header figure": [
                {
                    "id": "attmeLF6GWqLF3iOS",
                    "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/d6c5f674aeb427dd533cd2c60ab2b29f/f2f99dc0/80__clouds.jpg",
                    "filename": "80__clouds.jpg",
                    "size": 2334688,
                    "type": "image/jpeg",
                    "thumbnails": {
                        "small": {
                            "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/7c3dc033b1a7f77fcdeddb2f594a1feb/9a93ab8d",
                            "width": 36,
                            "height": 36
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/6145b560b5c807787814fcf9b39e6130/0f7d0049",
                            "width": 519,
                            "height": 512
                        },
                        "full": {
                            "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/ecebeb4705ba5531744d556242ddc081/20e10b2a",
                            "width": 2121,
                            "height": 2094
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "createdTime": "2019-02-12T09:53:52.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "recXiwDKIMSiGd2fn",
        "fields": {
            "header h1": "People",
            "Email": 2,
            "header figure": [
                {
                    "id": "attr1iy10UnygtRx0",
                    "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/67484295777d866d6610ef9f84f8bc53/81ae8e6b/A07.jpg",
                    "filename": "A07.jpg",
                    "size": 1014718,
                    "type": "image/jpeg",
                    "thumbnails": {
                        "small": {
                            "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/786cc58d3f5b82f4a8414d89b5ea48fb/4a214afc",
                            "width": 14,
                            "height": 36
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/3cb6be2be2b42be2c240f4f2bb9b7901/3bf2b62b",
                            "width": 512,
                            "height": 1288
                        },
                        "full": {
                            "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/4e56dafdcf39da1f35c1e2f9e96fda6c/07d91945",
                            "width": 800,
                            "height": 2013
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "createdTime": "2019-02-12T09:53:52.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "recvSJHL3EkSBprs9",
        "fields": {
            "Email": 3
        },
        "createdTime": "2019-02-12T09:53:52.000Z"
    }
],
"offset": "recvSJHL3EkSBprs9"
```

}

I'm able to extract the value for "header h1" key with the following jsx

```
<h2>{record.fields["header h1"]}</h2>
```

I'm now trying to extract the value from the "url" key. I've tried the following.

```
<img src={records.fields["header figure"]["url"]} />
```

and

```
<img src={records.fields["header figure"][0]["url"]} />
```

I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property "url" of undefined.Need some help with my syntax please

- List item

Comment: your records is an array, also you must do somthing like recoreds[0].fileds

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kvt4lb ?

Answer (score 0):

your records is an array, also you must specify wich position you want to read:

I tested your json with jq:

```
jq '.records[0].fields["header figure"][0]["url"]'
```

delivers

```
"https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/d6c5f674aeb427dd533cd2c60ab2b29f/f2f99dc0/80__clouds.jpg"
```

and

```
jq '.records[1].fields["header figure"][0]["url"]'
```

delivers

```
"https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/67484295777d866d6610ef9f84f8bc53/81ae8e6b/A07.jpg"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers. Weirdly this works in the react componentDidMount function, but not in the render function